# How can we improve our tech-writing tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have several tags relevant for questions about technical writing:

- [technical-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing)
- [api-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-documentation)
- [indexing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indexing)
- [examples](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples)

Plus there are many other tags that apply to lots of types of writing, including technical writing, like [tools](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools), [software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software), [editing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing), [style](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style), and [research](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research).

Among that first group, we started with just [technical-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing) and then at some point we added [api-documentation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-documentation) because that sub-category of tech writing has some different concerns and we want those questions to be easy to find.

API documentation isn't the only type of technical writing.  *Software documentation* isn't the only kind of technical writing, for that matter.  We're about to get some questions from the Technical Communication site, which is closing, so I looked at their tags.  They include:

- software-documentation
- user-guide
- terminology
- documentation-generator  (this is a type of software tool)
- automation (technical doc often uses automated build processes)
- data-visualization
- document-maintenance
- information-architecture
- design

Should we enrich our current tag set?  If so, how?  I'm not proposing that we add all these or that we use the existing names, but the context might help us think about how to better serve our tech-writing questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm a TechComm SE refugee, so I don't know how much my opinion counts on what Writing SE should do, but yes I think that would be helpful.

The first thing I did after joining Writing SE was favorite the tags [technical-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing), [software](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software), and [tools](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools). The main page list was still overwhelming, so I blocked every tag I saw about fiction writing and other things outside the realm of TechComm - now my main page feed actually shows me what I know and care about.

So I guess my point is that there are *so many* tags about other types of writing that adding some TechComm-specific ones would be nice. In addition to the existing tags [novel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel), [blog](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog), [novella](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novella), etc, how about **release-notes**, **user-guide**, **online-help**, or **embedded-assistance**? I see there's a tag for [microsoft-word](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) - how about some specific TechComm tools like **DITA** or at least **structured-authoring** and **single-sourcing**?

It may make sense to think about the types of tags that exist in Writing 
SE, and what some of their analogs might be in TechComm. A lot of the existing Writing SE tags can be clustered into ideas like genre, publication form, tools, and audience. The latter three are also concerns of TechComm folks. Perhaps an analog for genre is subject matter? (e.g. software, hardware, medical...)

Comment: You're a participant trying to make Writing stronger; your opinion matters.  Thanks for these great suggestions.  (Some of our current tags just kind of grew that way, and some I would change or remove were we starting from scratch.)

Comment: By embedded assistance, do you mean context-sensitive help?  Or is there a nuanced difference between the two?  (We'd probably make synonyms if not.)

Comment: My group uses them slightly differently - CSH as your traditional (?) icon in the corner or (i) next to a field. We use embedded user assistance to describe a wider variety of approaches that would include CSH, but also items more directly tied into the UI. However, I don't know that this is really a standard difference that others in the industry would use, or just our way of making a distinction for ease of internal discussion. Others may want to weigh in on this :)

Comment: Ok, got it.  So (to pick an annoying example) Clippy is embedded assistance?

Comment: Haha - yes, I suppose that's how we would classify it. But again, I'm not sure how legit this is as a real distinction/the proper terminology.

Comment: I agree with Monica's initial comment, your opinion matters. Writing SE isn't meant, and never was meant, to be only about *fiction* writing, even though that has become one major part of the site. My general opinion about tags is that if it genuinely helps to categorize questions, and is likely to be useful for more than a few questions, then it makes sense to add it as a tag and see if it takes off. Heck, I added a tag on Stack Overflow at one point which is now used by 280 questions...

Comment: Since you don't yet have the reputation to create new tags (that requires 150 rep on beta sites), particularly for new questions you can leave a note at the end of the question along the lines of, say, `Proposed new tag: [tag:release-notes]`. `[tag:xx]` will format the name `xx` as a tag blob, but not actually add it to the system. People with more reputation coming across that may then add it as a proper tag (or decide that it doesn't make sense for the site). Or, post a separate question on [meta] and make your case, including links to some example questions and a proposed tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That sounds like a good approach!

Comment: Based on this discussion I've created a couple of these, as I saw questions where they applied.  None of them have tag wikis yet.  (When we get there, I'd propose online-documentation as opposed to online-help, because not all such doc is "help".  The idea would be for questions that are specifically about that presentation form.)

Answer (score 3):

I think that 'research' is a bit of a vague name for a tag. It can mean both research about writing and writing for research (i.e. a paper or something like that). It appears both interpretations are used. I think it would be a good idea to split this tag into [scientific-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-writing) and [science-of-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-of-writing) or something similar.

It might be a good idea to have 'subtags' for the (broad) scientific disciplines: such as [formal-sciences](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-sciences), [empirical-sciences](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/empirical-sciences), [humanities](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humanities).

Comment: I agree that we need to do something about "research".  To add to the scientific confusion, we have "scientific-publishing", which I think is more about scientific *writing*, so we should do something about that.  Subtags for classes of sciences should be created the first time the distinction is relevant to a question.

Comment: @MonicaCellio 'scientific-publishing' sounds a bit off-topic to me. Although, I'm not sure what aspects of writing this site is aiming to cover. If it includes publication issues for writers of, say, novels, I guess that should be on-topic as well. At the very least that would be a much better fit for Academia.SE.

Comment: @Discretelizard 'scientific-publishing' could potentially cover things like writing for journal submissions (e.g. corresponding with editors and reviewers), but tbh, a lot of that field would probably be (and really, already is) better served over on [academia.se].

Comment: @Myles In addition, the most common answer on [academia.se] to questions about 'corresponding with editors and reviewers' is _ask your editor, [indication of how the editor might response but also making clear that it would have been better for all parties involved if you have just asked the editor in the first place]_

Comment: Note that I do think 'scientific writing' is something that has a firm place here in spite of [academia.se], for two reasons: 1) scientific writing need not necessarily be done in the context of academia, take e.g. private research but also the sizable group of science SE's; and 2) this site has expertise regarding (possibly technical) writing. While scientific writing is very specialised, it is still writing and the expertise of any kind of writer is likely relevant.